# Remove All Instances of a Specific Regular Expression From Text With Perl

Tags: text-processing, regular-expression, perl, text

I am looking for the correct Perl one-liner to remove all instances of a particular regular expression from a text file.

Namely, I want to remove all instances of [ immediately followed by a capital letter, then followed by any number of characters and spaces until ]. For instance, `[CP 5.491]` or `[MS 283: 56 (variant) in Colapietro, 1989, p. XIV]`.

I would like to accomplish this in Perl because the simple script I wrote to process my files is otherwise already in that language.

**Edit:**

After trying out the two perfectly adequate answers below, I realized that I made one mistake in my original question (sorry!): I would also need to delete instances where the left bracket is followed by `cf` instead of a capital letter, for instance `[cf. CP 2.282]`. How would I add that parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove:

- a `[` character (`\[`)
- immediately followed by a capital letter (`[A-Z]` Ascii only)
- or (alternation) by an string `cf` ( `([A-Z]|cf)` ).
- then followed by any number of characters and spaces  (`[^]]` not a `]`)
- until a `]` (`\]`).

You could use (in Perl) either of:

```
\[([A-Z]|cf)[^]]\]        # Ascii uppercase, avoid `]`
[[]([A-Z]|cf)[^]][]]      # A bit more confusing expression of the same.
[[]([A-Z]|cf).*?[]]       # Use a lazy quantifier (the shorter match).
[[](\p{Lu}|cf).*?[]]      # Unicode property: Letter Uppercase.
\[(\p{Lu}|cf).*?\]        # Probably easier to read.
```

If you do not use the negated range expression (`[^]]`) or the lazy match (`.*?`) the expression would match this whole string:

```
this part [CP 5.491] or this part [cf 283: 56 in Colapietro, 1989, p. XIV]
```

Not **each** part.

```
perl -pe '$_ =~ s/\[(\p{Lu}|cf).*?\]//g' file
```

Comment: Thank you for that exhaustive answer, your solution does exactly what I asked for! However, I realized that I forgot something in my original question, see my latest edit.

Comment: @Mindforms Answer edited....

Comment: Awesome, thank you again, it works perfectly, and better still, _I get it_... I had totally forgotten about `(...|...)` but that edit seems so simple now.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming only the ASCII character set of uppercase letters, this may suffice when you want to remove the matching line in its entirity:

```
perl -ne 'print unless m{\[([A-Z]|cf).*\]}' file
```

If you want only to excise the sections like "[CP 5.491], leaving the surrounding text:

```
perl -pe 's{\[([A-Z]|cf).*?\]}{}g' file
```

Comment: Thank you, that second one-liner is indeed exactly what I was looking for! That being said, I would like to understand what is the difference between the solution of @Isaac above (i.e. `perl -pe '$_ =~ s/\[[A-Z].*?\]//g' file`) and yours. :)

Comment: `$_ =~ s/...` is the same as simply `s/...` in this code. `$_` is the default upon which the substitution operates. @Isaac does a nice job of showing you different matching methods. The key here is to use a lazy match `.*?` as I did, or a negated range expression `[^]]` as he did. I prefer the lazy match as it looks less "noisy".

Comment: I see, thanks! Indeed, the code works the same without `$_ =~ `. I have a bit of Googling to do to properly understand what that default variable does, but there seems to be no lack of information about it.

Comment: @Mindforms As for `$_` see [here](https://perldoc.perl.org/5.30.0/perlvar.html#General-Variables).